# Group Velocity at the Boundary of the Brillouin Zone

Tags: waves, solid-state-physics, crystals, dispersion

I'm having trouble understanding why the dispersion relation $\omega(\vec{q})$ is extremal at the boundaries of the first Brillouin zone.

I understand why the dispersion relation is symmetric around zero $\omega(\vec{-q}) = \omega(\vec{q})$ and that the translational symmetry of the crystal implies that $\omega(\vec{q} + \vec{\tau}) = \omega(\vec{q})$ for any reciprocal lattice vector $\vec{\tau}$. This implies that the dispersion relation must be maximal for $\omega(\vec{\tau})$. I believe that these properties should be enough to proof that the dispersion relation is extremal at the boundary of the Brillouin zone, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Without further assumptions on the dispersion relation, this needn’t be true